# Can't submit my info from login form using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't figure out how to validate my credentials from a login form website using Selenium Python

Html source code

```
<div id="login_button_container">

<span id="login_quick_clock_container">

<a class="button1 clock_out" onclick="login_quick_clock();" 
onmouseover="XZF.Util.showHoverText(this, 'Clock out', {xoffset: 20})">03:45</a>

</span>

<a class="button1" onclick="XZF.Login.submit()">Log in</a>

</div>
```

The line corresponding to the submit button is

```
<a class="button1" onclick="XZF.Login.submit()">Log in</a>
```

I'm not great with html but I guess this is using a function "XZF.Login.submit()" .

Here is  what I tried with my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

# webpage url
url = 'https://xzf.clockapp.com/'

driverPath = 'chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)

driver.get(url)


username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_handle")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")

username.send_keys("myUserName")
password.send_keys("myPassWord")

driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button1").click()
```

I chose to find using the Class because there is no "ID" attribute but still when I do my script, it's filling out username / password properly but it's not clicking on the "login" button.

Any thoughts ?

Cheers,

Xzi.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("button1").click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because find_elements_by_class_name returns an array. If you only have 1 you should use find_element_by_class_name.

If you use find_elements_by_class_name you will need to index the button in the return results.

For example

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button1")[0].click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button1").click()
```

I would avoid finding elements by global class name, instead, use xpath.

Example
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[button/@class='button1']")

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list of elements.

You need to specify the element of that list.

If that website has just one element with `button1` class name you can use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button1").click()
```

Source: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name